# Not about to deserialize json kept as string in Python using json.load

Tags: python

```
strdata = strdata + json.dumps(data, default=lambda o: o.__dict__)
```

I'm using this to concatenate json data from various api calls, into a string.

Now, when I want to read the data/load the variable "strdata" into a json format, using

```
json.loads(strdata)
```

but it doesn't work. I presume that considering that I'm concatenating a serialized string with another, I should dump the entire strdata first and then load it again. But that doesn't work either.

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean?  Throws an exception?  Returns incorrect output?  Something else?

Comment: Maybe show a simple example of strdata?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Initialize `strdata` as a list:

```
strdata = []
```

Inside the loop, append the JSON dumps to the list:

```
strdata.append(json.dumps(data, default=lambda o: o.__dict__))
```

To store the list in a file:

```
json.dump(strdata, f)
```

To load the list from the file:

```
strdata = json.load(f)
```

To retrieve the original data (or the `data.__dict__` proxy), call json.loads on each item in `strdata`:

```
[json.loads(item) for item in strdata]
```

---

JSON has a [well-defined format](http://www.json.org/). You can not create valid JSON (such as a list of elements) by simply concatenating two JSON strings.

---

There is a more sophisticated way to handle this problem: use a custom encoder (`cls=CustomEncoder`), and a custom decoder (`object_hook=custom_decoder`):

```
import json

class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, x=1, y='bar'):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

class CustomEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, Foo):
            return obj.__dict__
        else:
            return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)

filename = '/tmp/test.json'
with open(filename, 'w') as f:
    json.dump(
        [Foo(1, 'manchego'), Foo(2, 'stilton'), [{'brie': Foo(3,'gruyere')}]],
        f, cls=CustomEncoder)

def custom_decoder(dct):
    try:
        return Foo(**dct)
    except TypeError:
        return dct

with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    newfoo = json.load(f, object_hook=custom_decoder)
print(newfoo)
# [{"y": "manchego", "x": 1}, {"y": "stilton", "x": 2}, [{"brie": {"y": "gruyere", "x": 3}}]]
```

The advantage of doing it this way is that it requires only one call to `json.dump` to store the data, and only one call to `json.load` to retrieve the data.

Comment: The only problem(?) being that I store the concatenated string in a file. How do I store a list into a file in python?

Comment: To store `strdata` in a file, you could serialize it too with `json.dump`.